# nodejs net client socket reconnect

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, client

```
var socket = new net.Socket();
socket.connect(PORT, HOST, function() {
    console.log("SOCKET CONNECTED TO: " + HOST + ":" + PORT);
    socket.write("Hello World!");
});
socket.on("error", function() {}); // need this line so it wont throw exception

// Add a "close" event handler for the client socket
socket.on("close", function() {
    console.log("Connection lost. How do I reconnect? setTimeout?");
});
```

How do I reconnect after it failed? Now if the connection is not successful, everything stops..

I've tried using setTimeout in close event, but then when the socket connects, the 'connect' event is fired multiple times..

Comment: Presumably you create a new socket object just like the first one.  You cannot reconnect the existing one - that just doesn't make sense conceptually.

Comment: But then I lose all the events attached to this socket object.. i.e socket.on('data'), I have to rebind that all over, I hoped if there is a better way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve reconnecting in the following way while keeping the event binding:

```
function connect() {
    var socket = new net.Socket();
        socket.connect(PORT, HOST, function() {
            console.log('SCOEKT CONNECTED TO: ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);
            socket.write('Hello World!');
        });

    socket.on('error', function() {}); // need this line so it wont throw exception

    // Add a 'close' event handler for the client socket
    socket.on('close', function() {
        connect();
    });
}
connect();
```

Comment: This way I'll have to put all my socket related code, like .on ('data'), inside the connect function?

Comment: You could write a function called for example `handleData` which is located outside of the `connect` function and put `socket.on('data', handleData);` in `connect`, that's no problem.

Comment: Ok that is good enough, I did hoped if there is something like socket.reconnect though, but I will do fine with that